# how to call global function from another global function with one parameter in iphone?

Tags: iphone

HiI am very new to iphone development.I am java background developer.So my approach is like java .

Here my requirement is that i want to call one global function from every view controller.
and from there i pass self.navigationController as a parameter. In that function i add some buton. when user click on that button it should call one more function and it should carry same object as a parameter.

please give me guidance. i tried as following but it is showing error at compiletime

Utilities.m

```
     +(void)setBacKButton:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
    {

        for(UIButton *btn in navigationController.navigationBar.subviews){
            if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                [btn removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }

        UIButton *btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn2.frame=CGRectMake(708, 0, 50, 54);
        [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:0];
        [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        // here i need to call bellow function when click on this button
//[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector() forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:btn2];  
    }
    +(void)gotoBack:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
    {
        [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

and i call that function from my viewcontroller as

```
[Utilities setBacKButton:self.navigationController];
```

please tell me how we can achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a navigation controller in your app Delegate ... and push your view controller using this.. follow the following code...

```
   //YourAppdelegate.h
   UINavigationController *navController; 
   @property(nonatomic,retain)UINavigationController *navController; 

  // your appdelegate.m

  navController = [UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
  self.window.rootViewController = navController ;
```

and now make your global function here (in appdelegate.m) like.......

```
 - (void)setBacKButton:(UINavigationController *)navigationController{
     // put your code here
  }
```

now call it from your view controllers where you have needed like this...

```
   // yourViewController.m
```

## import "yourAppdelegate.h"

and when you have to call that function just write these two lines..

```
  YourAppdelegate    *appdelegate = (YourAppdelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

  [appdelegate setBacKButton:self.navigationController];
```

may this will help you

Answer (score 2):

add a function in your app delegate.and call that function in all your view controllers.with an object of appdelegate.then with in that function add one button with id sender and do watever u want in the method.

Comment: thank you for replay but i want to implement one method to pop screen. for that purpose i need navigationcontroler object so how can i get that navigation controller object?

Comment: just initialise a navigation controller object in your appdelegate and push your view contriller to that navigation controller.that is the basic principle of being a navigation based project.so u need a view controller object only in that function and push it to the appdelegate navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

you would want to create a category of UINavigationBar.

UINavigationBar+customBackButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UINavigationBar (customBackButton)
- (void)setCustomBackButton;
@end
```

UINavigationBar+customBackButton.m

```
#import "UINavigationBar+customBackButton.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (customBackButton)

- (void)setCustomBackButton
{
    for(UIButton *btn in self.subviews)
    {
        if([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [btn removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UIButton *btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn2.frame=CGRectMake(708, 0, 50, 54);
    [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back.png"] forState:0];
    [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_back_h.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    // here i need to call bellow function when click on this button
    //[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector() forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:btn2];
}

@end
```

Then in any view controller you can import it like this

```
#import "UINavigationBar+customBackButton.h"

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setCustomBackButton];
```

Comment: How this approach actually navigate back to the previous view when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Following the response from @ewiinnnnn above, I came up with a way to use Custom Categories and have the back button navigate as expected:

```
// UIViewController+customBackButton.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewController (customBackButton)
- (void)setCustomBackButton;
@end


// UIViewController+customBackButton.m

#import "UIViewController+customBackButton.h"

@implementation UIViewController (customBackButton)


// sets my custom back button
- (void)setCustomBackButton
{

    UINavigationItem *navItem = self.navigationItem;

    UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *addButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"];
    UIImage *addButtonSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButtonHighlighted.png"];

    [customButton setBackgroundImage:addButton  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customButton setBackgroundImage:addButtonSelected  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    customButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, addButton.size.width, addButton.size.height);
    [customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navigateBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customButton];


    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;


}

// the action that is triggered when the back button is pressed
- (void)navigateBack {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

And then within a UIViewController:

```
// MyViewController.m

#import "UIViewController+customBackButton.h"

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // add back button to navcontroller
    [self setCustomBackButton];

}
```